# Dynamically generate list of protobuf rpc commands in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

Could you give me advice, how could one get list of possible grpc calls (and objects using in calling) in python?

More precisely, say I have a protobuf:

```
service MyService {
rpc Command1(Command1Request) returns (Command1Response);
rpc Command2(Command2Request) returns (Command2Response);
...
rpc CommandX(CommandXRequest) returns (CommandXResponse);
}
message Command1Request {
    uint64 param1 = 2;
}
```

What I want is to generate protobuf using console utility. I have argparse and want to be able to dynamically generate list of commands for my utility:

```
my_utility --Command1 --param1 <value>
my_utility --Command2 --param2 <value>
...
```

Right now I use dir() method to get list of objects and because of this have fixed the special naming convention for my protobuf: If I have "Command2Response" my object for call is "Command2Request" and method for invoke request is "Command2".

Are there more correct method to get list of possible calls (naming convention too prone to human errors)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for the server reflection in gRPC Python?

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server-reflection.md

Answer (score 0):

gRPC Python reflection document was recently added here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/python/server_reflection.md

Example is here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_server_with_reflection.py

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the generated python code of this protobuf is part of your utility tool, you can get all the type information defined in the .proto file through protobuf descriptors. For example:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/internal/descriptor_test.py#L635

In your case, it will be something like:

> service_descriptor = your_proto_pb2.DESCRIPTOR.services_by_name['MyService']

Once you have the service descriptor, you can get the list of rpc methods defined in this service, request/response types used in these methods and more. See:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/descriptor.py#L748